# Is there a way to post to a page from an app without having the user be an admin?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been trying to set up an app with the Facebook Graph API so users can login and post to Facebook (or set up a time to post, sort of like HootSuite) on a company page. The only problem I have is that the user has to be an admin on the page to post on it.

What I would like to have is the app post the status/photo/whatever to the page without having the user to login as themselves (so they don't have to be an admin of the page to post to it).

Is there any way of doing this at all though an app?

Comment: You need to ask user to grant you relevant permission in order for your Application to post on that user wall, see permission [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/)

Answer (score 0):

You could get a page access token, and use that to post – but then all posts will be from the page itself I suppose.

Otherwise, you’d have to set up the page so that everyone could post to their wall.

Comment: I don't think so, I need to (if possible) skip the user login altogether and have the app work as the admin and post on the page as an admin. If that makes any sense/is possible.

Comment: By posting as admin, you mean as an actual _user_ who has admin rights to that page? Then you’d have to get an user access token from that user (and renew it when it expires). But if you want to post as that page, then the page access token is your way to go.

Comment: Right, but is there a way for the app to post as a page without any user authentication?

Comment: You have to get a page access token only once.